# How to display 2 BarVisualizers?

Tags: java, android

I am using the library [audio-visualizer-android](https://github.com/gauravk95/audio-visualizer-android). I am getting `BarVisualizer` from the constructor of my class and use the following code to display the BarVisualizer:

```java
int audioSessionId = mediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId();
if (audioSessionId != -1) {
    _barTop.setAudioSessionId(audioSessionId);
}
```

Well, that works fine but what I want is to display 2 BarVisualizers. This is what I have tried:

```java
int audioSessionId = mediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId();
if (audioSessionId != -1) {
    _barTop.setEnabled(false);
    _barBottom.setEnabled(false);
    _barTop.setAudioSessionId(audioSessionId);
    _barBottom.setAudioSessionId(audioSessionId);
}
```

It gives me the error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: setCaptureSize() called in wrong
> state: 2

When using only 1 of them, it works fine but by using both of them, I get the error and the app crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue that should be raised with the library author(s), as it doesn't support multiple visualizers attached to the same audio session.

---

But you can hack in that functionality by extending `BarVisualizer` and using that new class everywhere as a replacement:

```
public class CopyBarVisualizer extends BarVisualizer {
    private List<UpdateListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public CopyBarVisualizer(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CopyBarVisualizer(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CopyBarVisualizer(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public void addUpdateListener(UpdateListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void copyFrom(CopyBarVisualizer other) {
        other.addUpdateListener(new UpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void update(byte[] data) {
                mRawAudioBytes = data;
                CopyBarVisualizer.this.invalidate();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidate() {
        super.invalidate();
        for (UpdateListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.update(mRawAudioBytes);
        }
    }

    public interface UpdateListener {
        void update(byte[] data);
    }
}
```

Then initialize like this:

```
copyVisualizer.setAudioSessionId(audioSessionId);
copyVisualizer2.copyFrom(copyVisualizer);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I get the error *java.lang.ClassCastException: com.gauravk.audiovisualizer.visualizer.BarVisualizer cannot be cast to ch.yourclick.kitt.classes.CopyBarVisualizer*. Please see how I tried to initialize on https://www.codepile.net/pile/3G7b2y9r (MainActivity) and https://www.codepile.net/pile/y4ZbZl4n (Scanner).

Comment: You need to update your layout file as well.

Comment: Oh, I see. That works great, thank you so much!

Comment: I can copy the visualizer only once. Is there also a way how I could copy it multiple times?